# Polyglot opening book: getting incorrect moves

Tags: engines, programming

I am in the process of adding an opening book to my C++ engine and I hit a problem. Here is what I have:

- The Perfect2021.bin opening book that I would like to use.
- The function that creates the polyglot hash for the board. I tested this with many boards, and it is correct.

Now I would like to retrieve and for now only print all the moves my engine can make in a position, according to the book. I tried it with the following method:

```
move opening_book::getBookMove(const chessboard& board, const game_information& info) {
        uint64 boardKey = polyKeyFromBoard(board, info); //get key for board
        std::cout << "Finding moves for board key: " << std::hex << boardKey << std::dec << std::endl;
        unsigned short moveKey;
        //list moves from the book
        for(polyglot_book_entry* entry = entries; entry < entries + entriesNumber; entry++) {
            //apparently I need to swap bits for these
            if(boardKey == swap_uint64(entry->boardKey)) { //found the board in the book
                moveKey = swap_uint16(entry->move);
                unsigned short fromFile = (moveKey>>6)&7, fromRank = (moveKey>>9)&7,
                               toFile = (moveKey>>0)&7, toRank = (moveKey>>3)&7;
                unsigned int fromSquare = (8 * fromRank) + fromFile,
                             toSquare = (8 * toRank) + toFile;
                std::cout << "Move found: " << createSquareName(fromSquare) << createSquareName(toSquare) << std::endl;
            }
        }
        return move(); //not returning actual move right now
    }
```

But when I for example make my engine play black and I open the game on white with the move *e2e4* then the following is printed upon the engine checking the opening book:

```
Finding moves for board key: 823c9b50fd114196
Move found: c2c4
Move found: e2e4
Move found: c2c3
Move found: e2e3
```

The board key is correct. It is one of the test cases on [this](http://hgm.nubati.net/book_format.html) site. However, as you can see the moves that are found seem to be for white.

Can someone please help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem: my board representation was different and while my ranks are also from 0-7, but they are counted from the black side, while in the polyglot encoding, they are counted from the white side (which makes sense).

So I had to invert my ranks like so:

```
unsigned short fromFile = (moveKey>>6)&7,
                          fromRank = 7 - ((moveKey>>9)&7),
                          toFile = (moveKey>>0)&7,
                          toRank = 7 - ((moveKey>>3)&7);
```

Files remain unchanged. I am now getting reasonable output:

```
Finding moves for board key: 823c9b50fd114196
Move found: c7c5
Move found: e7e5
Move found: c7c6
Move found: e7e6
```